# iPhone compile error: Invalid Suffix "_0" on Integer Constant on UIAccelerometer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, compiler-construction, uikit

I have been getting a really strange error using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 3.2.5 AND the latest Xcode 4 where I can build my code on debug on the simulator, but as soon as I try to deploy it onto a device (or build in 'release' mode) I get a really strange compile error on **UIAccelerometer.h** that resides in the UIKitFramework. The error message is:

> invalid suffix "_0" on integer constant

The line in **UIAccelerometer.h** that causes the issue is:

```
UIKIT_CLASS_AVAILABLE(2_0) @interface UIAccelerometer : NSObject
```

I have obviously not changed the UIKit Framework, so I can't understand at all why I'm getting this error. I've tried changing deployment targets to all iOS SDKs, tried changing any settings with minSdk versions on Xcode, etc.

Comment: It sounds like your compile settings are wrong, but editing the SDK should work...

Comment: I am getting the same error in The MFMessageComposeViewController.h after adding MessageUI.framework.